# How to convert a decimal number into a binary list with fixed number of bits in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose I have the decimal number 8, and I want to conver it into a binary list of length 8.
It means if I give input as 8, I should get output as [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]. I am looking for an inbuilt command in python that can do that in a very short time (in nano-seconds).

I have tried the foolowing comman which is giving me error:

```
[int(x) for x in list('{0:8b}'.format(8))]
```

The error I am getting is

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

Comment: {0:08b} would work

Answer (score 2):

You can do with list comprehension.

```
>>> [int(i) for i in bin(8)[2:].zfill(8)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

`bin(8)` return the binary representation of an integer `8` and it's always prefixed with `0b`. So `bin(8)[2:]` is to remove these first two characters(ie, `0b`). And then you can use `.zfill(8)` to pad a numeric string with zeros on the left(with the given width `8`)

Answer (score 0):

You could build an f-string then iterate over that with *map()* as follows:

```
n = 8

lst = list(map(int, f'{n:08b}'))

print(lst)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
[function(item) for item in list]
```

Will go through all items in `list`, and return a list witch all items handled by function.

Second:

```
'[index]:[width][type]'.format(input)
'{0:8b}'.format(8)
```

Means convert input in index 0:`8` to binary string `1000`, and fill space until width is `8`. So the result of `'{0:8b}'.format(8)` is     `1000`.(Please search `.format()` for more informations)

So what it's trying to do is:

```
[int(x) for x in list('    1000'.format(8))]
```

The error you got is because you are trying to parse space(`' '`) to int.

You can try:
Fill width with `0`:

```
[int(x) for x in list('{0:08b}'.format(8))]
```